# fastest way to animate a lot of graphic elements in JavaFX

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, java-8, vector-graphics

I'm taking my first steps in JavaFX. I want to animate a lot of graphic elements (ellipses, bézier curves, not images) with javafx. These elements are organized in groups of about 10 elements that have to move together. I'm trying to achieve 60 fps and I want to move thousands of these elements.

There are at least four ways to do this:

- Using a single canvas, and its graphical context to draw directly at every frame.
- Using groups and nodes. Each element is a node. I like this way because there are a lot of classes that can be used to draw easily what I need, and the logical structure of nodes and groups is just what I need.
- Each group is a canvas. Draw its elements in its constructor using the canvas graphical context, and then move all the canvases at each frame.
- Creating images with the elements that have to stick together, and then move these images. I haven't found already how this can be done, but I suppose it's not hard. The elements may change from time to time, so I will need to recreate some images, but only once in a while.

My question is, which of these ways (or another) would be the fastest way to do it? In particular, does the use of a lot of nodes and groups has a high performance impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with option two as this seems to logically fit your needs best. It is also the most straight forward and cleanest way of doing it with JavaFX. If it later turns out that the performance is not good enough you can try to improve this by using caching together with the appropriate cache hints. For example you can optimize your code for speed or for quality this way. This even works dynamically because you can switch between these cache hints depending on the state of your application. If you switch caching on for a group this has basically the same effect as drawing it into a canvas or an image.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the cache hints. Will try and report.

Comment: With cache activated and cacheHints set at speed I can rotate more 2000 overlapping groups keeping a rate of 60 FPS. Not bad :)